# Does MariaDB 5.5.56 have INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_METRICS?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.5, mariadb, information-schema

I'm trying to debug why I don't have `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_METRICS`. I'm uncertain because I see it in the MySQL 5.5 reference glossary: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/search/?d=10&p=1&q=innodb_metrics.

```
mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 5.5.56-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

When I try to configure it through *my.cnf* I get:

```
mysqld: unknown variable "innodb_monitor_enable"
```

When I try to configure it through the MySQL CLI I get:

```
MariaDB [(none)]>  SET GLOBAL innodb_monitor_enable = trx_rw_commits;
ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'innodb_monitor_enable'
MariaDB [(none)]>  SET GLOBAL innodb_monitor_enable = trx_nl_ro_commits;
ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'innodb_monitor_enable'
MariaDB [(none)]>  SET GLOBAL innodb_monitor_enable = trx_ro_commits;
ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'innodb_monitor_enable'
MariaDB [(none)]>  SET GLOBAL innodb_monitor_enable = trx_rollbacks;
ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'innodb_monitor_enable'
```

My guess is that it was introduced in 5.6 because
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-information-schema-metrics-table.html redirects to 8.0 and 5.6 works.

**Additional info**

Turns out that, as shown below

```
SELECT VERSION()
    -> ;
+----------------+
| VERSION()      |
+----------------+
| 5.5.56-MariaDB |
+----------------+
```

...I was looking in the wrong place. I actually am using MariaDB as the database management system, and @danblack pointed out it was released in 10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version string indicate your client version is MariaDB. Making the assumption that your server is too and looking at the [MariaDB kb](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/information-schema-innodb_metrics-table/) INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_METRICS was added in 10.0.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I found the manual for my version mariadb. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/mariadb-55/

Answer (score 1):

> ----- 2011-04-11 5.6.2 Developer Milestone -- INFORMATION_SCHEMA Table for InnoDB Metrics -- InnoDB -----
>
> A new INFORMATION_SCHEMA table, [INNODB_METRICS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-metrics-table.html), lets you query low-level InnoDB performance information, getting cumulative counts, averages, and minimum/maximum values for internal aspects of the storage engine operation. You can start, stop, and reset the metrics counters using the [innodb_monitor_enable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_monitor_enable), [innodb_monitor_disable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_monitor_disable), [innodb_monitor_reset](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_monitor_reset), and [innodb_monitor_reset_all](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_monitor_reset_all) system variables.

I can't say specifically when (or if) it was folded into MySQL other than to say that there is no hint of it being backported into MariaDB 5.5.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql --version` only shows the version of the client, not the server. `SELECT VERSION()` is a good server indication.

Going by your assertion that you are really using MySQL and not MariaDB, I would concur with your guess that it was added in 5.6

Comment: My bad. It's MariaDB. I thought it was just MariaDB printing the Mysql version. I'll add the select version() result to the article.

Comment: All good. SO is all about learning :-)